# How can I compute this?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have the following numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

my_data = np.array(
[[1, 1, 1],
 [2, 2, 2],
 [3, 3, 3],
 [4, 4, 4],
 [5, 5, 5]])

# obtain the length
n = len(my_data) # 5
```

I want to do this computation for t=0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

1. take the t-th row
2. compute dot product of the t-th row and the entire array
3. compute sum
4. divide by (n-t)
5. retun all the results as an array

I.e.

```
t = 0
v0 = my_data[t:,]
my_data_dot = np.dot(my_data, v0)
my_data_sum = np.sum(my_data_dot)/(n-t)
```

How can I do this without using looping statements?

Please show me the simplest way.

Comment: I suggest you replace with a more descriptive question, or folks will downvote you.

Comment: `my_data` is a list, not an array. You're missing a call to `np.array()`.

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct problem.... if t=5 and n=5 then you will have a division by 0.

Comment: You cannot start from zero or insert zero. There is no zero from list

Comment: To emphasize what Captain Chaos said above -- one of the most important purposes of a question's title, the purpose that lasts _beyond_ the time when your question gets answered, is _helping other people with the same problem find your question and learn from its answers_. Nobody can tell what "this" is when they see "How can I compute this" in their search results, so it's a useless title to people trying to tell if a question and its answers will help as they attempt to find solutions to their own problem.

Comment: (See also [Stack Overflow: The Wikipedia of Long-Tail Programming Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/); a good title describes a problem well enough to be the subject of an encyclopedia article about how to solve that problem).

Answer (score 1):

You can use matrix multiplication and [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
>>> t_values = np.arange(0, 5)
>>> result = ((my_data @ my_data.T) / (n - t_values)).sum(axis=0)
>>> result
array([  9. ,  22.5,  45. ,  90. , 225. ])
```

---

Original code test (with correction and loop):

```
my_data = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5]])
n = len(my_data)
for t in range(5):
    v = my_data[t, :] # t-th row
    my_data_dot = np.dot(my_data, v)
    my_data_sum = np.sum(my_data_dot)/(n - t)
    print(my_data_sum)
```

Output:

```
9.0
22.5
45.0
90.0
225.0
```